# Saving with angular $resource.save causes view to redraw/reflow due to collection watcher

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a model which I load and store using $resource. The model is an aggregate and has nested collections inside, which are binded to an html view using ng-repeat.

Model:

```
{
    someRootField: "blabla",
    sectionCollection: [
        {
            name: "section1"
            ....
        },
        {
            name: "section2",
            ....
        }
    ]
}
```

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="section in myModel.sectionCollection">
...
</div>
```

controller:

```
MyModelResource = $resource(config.api4resource + 'models/:id', {id:'@_id'});
$scope.myModel = MyModelResource.get({id: xxxx});
```

The problem: when I use $save on this model, it causes a reload/redraw of some portions of the screen (seems not the root fields, but the collection related ones), if some binded elements within the sections are inputs, focus is lost too. I did some debugging and here is what I think is happening.

1. When I save the model, the results from the POST command mirror the body of the request, and myModel is being repopulated with it. Simple fields in the root of the model are pretty much the same, so the watch() mechanism doesn't detect a change there, however the the objects in the sectionCollection array are different, as they are compared not by their contents but by an equality of the references and fail, this causes the ui controls associated with the collection to be completely reloaded/redrawn.

There is this code in $watchCollectionWatch() in angular:

```
      } else if (isArrayLike(newValue)) {
        if (oldValue !== internalArray) {
          // we are transitioning from something which was not an array into array.
          oldValue = internalArray;
          oldLength = oldValue.length = 0;
          changeDetected++;
        }

        newLength = newValue.length;

        if (oldLength !== newLength) {
          // if lengths do not match we need to trigger change notification
          changeDetected++;
          oldValue.length = oldLength = newLength;
        }
        // copy the items to oldValue and look for changes.
        for (var i = 0; i < newLength; i++) {
          if (oldValue[i] !== newValue[i]) {
            changeDetected++;
            oldValue[i] = newValue[i];
          }
        }
      }
```

in my case, I've definitely seen the oldValue[i] = newValue[i] comparison fail, the objects were different. One of the reason is oldValue contained variables prefixed with $ that were referring back to the scopes that were previously created for each item.

The question is, how can I prevent a reflow? Or how can I do it differently to avoid it. Keeping myself two copies of the model, one for $resource and another for binding to view and synchronizing between them manually does not seem right.

Thanks!

Comment: It whould be very handy to have you code example on plnkr.co

Comment: $save will update your model and thus template should be rerendered - why this is problem for you?

Comment: when template is being rerendered, images are reloaded, and if form inputs are involved, they are losing their focus.

Comment: Untill you don't have thousands of saving operations, maybe image rerendering is not such a big deal? Also, you can remember element with focus before saving and restore it after. Any way, you can use $http as I show below in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) service to avoid model updates that $save cause:

```
$scope.save2 = ->  $http.get 'blah_new.json'
```

I used `get` in example but you can use whatever you need from [this list of shortcut methods](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#description_shortcut-methods). And here is a simple example [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8mZZzqaElrzil4qD4su4?p=preview).

Also it's simple to save elemen's focus after rerendering:

```
  $scope.save = -> 
    active = document.activeElement.getAttribute 'id'
    $scope.user1.$save ->
      document.getElementById(active).focus()
```

Comment: I modified your plank to more resemble my case. http://plnkr.co/edit/GVLeuSV2YFZDokMOXDBD?p=preview try editing one of the friends and then press TAB to move focus to the next field.

Comment: I haven't checked but I suspect this solution has a flaw - it does not refocus the element at the cursor position that the user was at.